# How to share org.w3c.dom related code in a jvm + js Kotlin Multiplatform project?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I would like to write some `org.w3c.dom.Node`-related code in the `commonMain` source set but the compiler is not happy:

```kotlin
import org.w3c.dom.Node // compiler error here: Unresolved reference: Node

fun sayHello(node: Node) {
    node.ownerDocument!!.createElement("div").textContent = "hello"
}
```

Is there any way to do so? My goal is to use this common code to process XML in the `jvm` part, and to process the browser DOM in `js` part.

Please note that the same code is compiling properly in the `jvmMain` and `jsMain` source sets.

Below is a bit of information about my setup.

I have created a Kotlin Multiplatform Library project using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.
[image: new project wizard]

Then I removed the native source set to keep only `common`, `jvm` and `js` (browser target).
[image: project source sets]

I changed the kotlin version to `1.5.20` in `build.gradle.kts` (just in case it may help, it was `1.4.32` before) :

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.webpack.KotlinWebpack

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.5.20"
    application
}

group = "me.bfreuden.kotlin"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
        }
        testRuns["test"].executionTask.configure {
            useJUnit()
        }
        withJava()
    }
    js(IR) {
        moduleName = "hello"
        binaries.executable()
        browser {
            webpackTask {
                output.libraryTarget = "commonjs2"
            }
            commonWebpackConfig {
                cssSupport.enabled = true
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting 
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val jvmMain by getting
        val jvmTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
            }
        }
        val jsMain by getting
        val jsTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-js"))
            }
        }
    }
}

application {
    mainClass.set("MainKt")
}

tasks.getByName<KotlinWebpack>("jsBrowserProductionWebpack") {
    outputFileName = "hello.js"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check out the Node [implementation for Kotlin/JS](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/org.w3c.dom/-node/)
you can see that it's an `abstract class Node : EventTarget`, while on JVM is `interface Node`.

You probably need to create your own `expect/actual` declarations for now:
declare `expect` on abstract classes and suppress errors about `expect/actual` mismatch for interfaces.

[Providing an actual interface for an expected abstract class](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-28473) is something in progress, though once fixed maybe commonizer could infer the similarities between kotlin-stdlib's `org.w3c.dom` API and the one provided by the JVM

Comment: I didn't know those `expect/actual` keywords. Thank you. I can declare an `expect`ed `Node` class or interface in common (only defining the methods I want to use), but I don't see any way to associate it to their built-in counterparts in jvm or js. Do you? So I guess the answer to my original question is unfortunately _not the moment_, right?